# Unable to create Hyperlink from Excel 2010 to a Bookmark in Word 2010 document

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

I have tried but am not able to create Hyperlink from Excel 2010 to a Bookmark in Word 2010 document.

The bookmark is in place in word document. But while clicking on Bookmarks button after browsing to the Word Document in the "Create Hyperlink" box of the Excel, I get error saying the word document could not be opened or parsed.

Note that the format of both the Word and Excel files is Office 2010.

Please let me know if there is a solution to this problem. Leave a comment if more info is required on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to click the "Bookmark" button. Rather append the bookmark name after the pound character when creating the hyperlink in Excel.

So if I have a bookmark called Test01 in my abc.docx file. I would have "Test.docx#Test01" in the Address field of the hyperlink dialog box in Excel.

Source:
http://www.davidgiard.com/2008/04/17/ExcelLinksToWordBookmarks.aspx

Comment: Yup, I tried that as well.
It saves you from the error but works as a Hyperlink to the document (not to the bookmark in the document).

For instance, if my #bookmark is placed at the 2nd page of the document, it will land me only to the first page, always.

Comment: That is very strange because I tried it out myself before posting. I just tried it again, are you sure your bookmark is working? Can you check the bookmark in Word? I made a bookmark on page 9 of a document, the link in Excel takes me right to it.

Comment: Yes, I checked the bookmark in Word and I am able to nevigate to bookmarks on diffenent pages.
But it is not working via Excel.
I am using Office 2010. Which version you are using?

Comment: I too am using Office 2010.

Comment: That's very strange... 
MyABAP_K.docx#Smartforms
This is how my "Address" looks like.
I will tell you about some other settings as well, don't know if I am doing something wrong!!!
My link is to "Existing File or Web Page"
Look in is set to "Current Folder"

Comment: Thank You, This original solution worked for me without issue. One suggestion would be to of course verify that you are putting the #(Bookmark Name) after the "docx" into the "Address" field rather than the "Text to display:" field.